# What is the meaning of A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client  error message

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to send an email via my web project using [Free text box](http://freetextbox.com/) control.It is an text editor . but I've got this error.

**A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (FreeTextBox1="**hello my dear**").**
I set the ValidateRequest=false  and I set the isbodyHtml=true. but It doesn't work .

what should I do?

Comment: @Radu why ? its a nice round number...

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the answer on this question:

[ValidateRequest="false" doesn't work in Asp.Net 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4)

This is a change in .net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before.

You need to also add  to your web.config file.

If you put your page into debug mode and read the text with the error message it tells you what to add and where to add it.  I cant remember 100% why the error occurs, I think it's something to do with page content on postback and the browser thinking there is harmfull code in there.

See also:  [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

and

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297679/A-potentially-dangerous-Request-Form-value-was-det

for a more complete explanation and solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running .NET 4.0, add this in your web.config (under system.web)

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

FreeTexBox control and  "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

You can try another decision

```
 if(!this.Page.ClientScript.IsOnSubmitStatementRegistered("Replace"))
{
 string script = @"if (Page_IsValid){FTB_API['" + txtBox.ClientID + @"'].initialized=false;   FTB_API['"  + txtBox.ClientID + @"'].htmlEditor.value=FTB_FreeTextBox.prototype.HtmlEncode( FTB_API['" + txtBox.ClientID + @"'].htmlEditor.value);}";
 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.Page.GetType(), "Replace", script);
}
```

and don't forget to replace symbols when you send string from server to the client application

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourstring)) txtBox.Text= yourstring.Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("&quot;", ('"').ToString()).Replace("&#146;", "'");
```